# Update an Excel worksheet using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

I am able to insert and read data of an Excel file but unable to update the data using `article_no` as trigger,

I have tried this

```
 Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
    cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\crys\Desktop\TEST\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""")
    cn.Open()
    With cm
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "UPDATE [up$] SET name = '" & TextBox2.Text & "', QC_status ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "', reason='" & TextBox3.Text & "', date='" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' WHERE article_no = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        If (ExecuteQuery(.CommandText) = True) Then
            MsgBox("record updated")
        End If
    End With


    cn.Close()
```

But it is showing me an error `invalid object 'up$'`.
Please someone help me fix this problem.

Comment: @jigar..what is the name of your sheet?

Comment: 'up' is the name of my sheet which i want to update

Comment: @jigar..i was not able to find any error in your code. Can you check once whether you are connection to document at the correct path.I mean connection string.

Comment: @jigar..may be the problem is with the connection string..

Comment: Please recheck if the name of the sheet is "up" and not "up " or " up" or " up "

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/excel-97-2003-xls-files-with-ace-oledb-120/

Comment: connection string is right

Comment: Do you need to wrap the date field name in square brackets?

Comment: no i jst want to update the contents with article_no as trigger with new values

Comment: I know, I suspect that Date is a reserved word - therefore needs to be wrapped in square brackets, have you tried it?

Comment: no its not reserved still trying but getting same error invalid object name up$ do u have any idea regarding it my sheet name is also proper and i ma able to retrieve data also bt unable to update

Comment: here date is the column name

Comment: Does the cell you are trying to update contain a formula?

Comment: no its just a simple data ,no formulas.

Comment: @jigar..try to rename the sheet and run again.

Comment: did already but the same result

Comment: i got code to update my excel sheet but when i am trying the same for the shared workbook i am unable to update the data from a shared workbook can anyone help me out please

Answer (score 1):

finally got my query right for updating excel sheet, code goes like this :

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
 Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\crysol\Desktop\TEST\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""")
cn.Open()
With cm
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandText = "update [up$] set [name]=?, [QC_status]=?, [reason]=?, [date]=? WHERE [article_no]=?"
    cm = New OleDbCommand(.CommandText, cn)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox2.Text)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox3.Text)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTimePicker1.Text)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox1.Text)
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL")
    con.Close()
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

**Generally , it is how its done. I am not able to find any error in your code:**

```
Imports System.Data
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim myCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
            Dim sql As String

            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
            ("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + _
            "'c:\testfile.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

            MyConnection.Open()
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection
            sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set name = 'New Name' where id=1"
            myCommand.CommandText = sql
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        MsgBox("Updated ")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: it showing syntax error in Update and erro in line  myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @jigar: the above code is the right way to do it :) Which VS version are you using? I see you have tagged it as vs 2010

Comment: @Can you post the complete code in your question. Also did you check if the sheet name in your workbook has any spaces?

Comment: instead of name='New Name' can we enter name '" & textbox2.text & "'

Comment: ya i checked the sheet name it does not have any spaces infact i am able to retrieve the data from that particular sheet

Comment: @siddhart i have given complete code that i have tried for updation

Comment: @Avinash still not getting the solution is there any other option of doing it.

Comment: i got code to update my excel sheet but when i am trying the same for the shared workbook i am unable to update the data from a shared workbook can anyone help me out please